# Manual bean autowiring doesn't work in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, junit

My Junit test code looks like this.

```
private static boolean setupDone = false;
private Box box;

@Before
public void setup(){

  if (setupDone){
    return true;
  }

  box = new BoxCreator(this.applicationContext);

  applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(box);

  setupDone = true;
}

@Test
public void Test1(){
  String response = box.getBoxResponse();

  ...asserts go here as usual....
}

@Test
public void Test2(){
 String response = box.getBoxResponse();

 ...asserts go here as usual....
}
```

Now what happens is that Setup method runs only once as desired by virtue of setupDone variable.

Setup method after creating an instance of Box object autowires it as seen in the code above. Intention is to have a singleton of this class and use the same instance in every test.

Now the problem is that whichever test method runs first gets the value of box object and the second test method sees box as null. Not sure why it becomes null when the second test method is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect its not using the same instance of the test class for each test method's run.

If you make "box" static, it might work better. Note that "setupDone" and "box" are initialized in the @Before method together and should reside in the same place whether its the class as for statics or the instance as for merely global variables.

The problem with that is that if one test modifies the state of the object or its inner objects, a following test might not work right.

Comment: So you mean to say different test in the same test class would have different application contexts ?

Comment: Each test has a different 'this' and all its instance variables. Static variables remain with the class and are the same no matter what instance of 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

As Lee Meador mentioned, JUnit creates a new instance of the test class before invoking each @Test method. By doing this it provides independence between test methods and avoids unintentional side effects in the test code. Each test should be individually executed without any effect of the previous test and hence should have different application contexts in your case.

Comment: And how does application context or bean factory work in JUnit tests then ? Every test would have it's own instance of test class and a separate application context or bean factory ? Is that how it works ?